# how to adjust the view to land scape mode when application launches in landscape mode

Tags: ipad, setorientation

i have a split view in ipad and its working fine when i launches it in poprtrait but is showing in portrait views in landscape also...

how to automatically adjust the views in land scape mode when app first launches....

Answer (score 0):

Set (or correct) the autosizing parameters for your subviews, either in IB or programmatically.